# School project won't save text

Tags: c#

I need help on why the text won't save to the file after first time.

Text won't save to the file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Project_OSO
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("     Name Database      \r");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------\n");
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}Hello, {name}, on {currentDate:d} at {currentDate:t}! Welcome to Name Database");
            //File and path you want to create and write to
            string fileName = @"C:\Users\Bruger\Desktop\NameDataBase";
            //Check if the file exists
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                 //Create the file and use streamWriter to write text to it.
                //If the file existence is not check, this will overwrite said file.
                //Use the using block so the file can close and variable disposed correctly
```

I have tried to find a way to get file to save, right now it saving the first time on a  new file but when there is text in the file it won't save the new text.

```
                using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(fileName))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine} { name} on the date {currentDate:d} at {currentDate:t}");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("------------------------\r");
            Console.WriteLine("     Name Database      \n");
    
            Console.Write($"{Environment.NewLine}Press to exit");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overwriting file with File.CreateText (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176762/overwriting-file-with-file-createtext-c)

Comment: You check to see if the file exists and if it does you do not write to it.  Use StreamWriter with the file option append.  If the file does not exist then it gets created.  See here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=net-6.0#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileStreamOptions_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specifically have a check that skips the file saving if a file already exists.

I would assume you want to [append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=net-6.0) to the file if it already exists.

Comment: **i add AppendText so it looks like this** 
'using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))' 
**but it still don't work for me. and Edit Filename to path**

Comment: @MagnJakoo Did you remove the `!File.Exists(fileName)` check?